# route files to correct folders in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, linux-kernel

I am new to linux, had some concerns while developing a script

**Question**: I have two folders/paths

1. /data/VCR/PRE
2. /data/VCR/MSI

I have number of files sitting under some xyz folder. My requirement is to route the files from the xyz folder to the default path which is 1. and only selected files go to path 2.

```
EXPORT DEFAULT_DEST=/data/VCR/PRE
EXPORT PRIVATE_DEST=/data/VCR/MSI
IF[filename=a or filename=b];
then
mv a $PRIVATE_DEST
else
mv $DEFAULT_DEST
```

My linux skills are naive please excuse the brevity in the syntax as its not proper. What would be the best way to implement such kind of a situation.

Comment: Bear in mind that `[` is a *command*, not part of bash's scripting syntax. Run `man test` for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move `xyz/a` and `xyz/b` to the private directory and then move the remainder of `xyz`'s files to the public directory, do:

```
mv xyz/a xyz/b /data/VCR/MSI/
mv xyz/* /data/VCR/PRE
```

If you really want to use an `if` statement, then:

```
for filename in xyz/*
do
    if [ "$filename" = xyz/a -o "$filename" = xyz/b ]
    then
        mv "$filename"  /data/VCR/MSI/
    else
        mv "$filename" /data/VCR/PRE/
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thats easy. But i am just curious how can we do this with an if statement